# EnableTransactionManagement cannot be resolved to a type 2

Tags: java

[image: the problem]

I am having problem "EnableTransactionManagement cannot be resolved to a type" though I have spring-tx jar already in my project. Can someone please suggest me what I am doing wrong. I am using Hibernate 4, Eclipse, Spring version 4.3.2. I am posting snapshot of my problem.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add **spring-orm** dependency into your pom.xml file.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I was adding spring-orm version 4.3.2 dependency. It worked after changing my version to 4.3.3. Thankyou pratik!